# HTML Character encoding affect encoding of input submission?

Tags: html, forms, input, character-encoding

Does the character encoding of an html page affect the character encoding of characters submitted via an input field (i.e. what a user is typing/what gets submitted), or is it the encoding of the display of the page only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Browsers encode form data in the encoding of the page containing the form.

Comment: You have a link to w3c or something saying this? I believe you, but I need something in writing for the engineers. ;-)

Comment: Only thing I can find on w3c so far is the accept-charset attribute for the form tag.

Comment: 10 years of experience on the subject. Tell them to prove the contrary if they don't believe me.